# Styles don't apply on CSS scoped component

Tags: css, vue.js

I have following simple component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-form-group label="From:" label-align="left" label-for="nested-from">
            <date-pick :displayFormat="'DD/MM/YYYY'" v-model.trim="search_form.date_from"></date-pick>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'simpleComp'
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "~vue-date-pick/src/vueDatePick.scss";

.vdpComponent.vdpWithInput > input {
  @extend .form-control !optional;
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid blue !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
```

here is the screenshot on console:

[image]

This's just a sample of a big project, basically I have an input in my component and styles don't get applied to it, but if I remove `scoped` then everything is back on track, but I want to keep it in scoped level.

I searched a bit and find this answer from SO:

> For some reason, scoped styles don't get applied during hot reload when they are first added to the component. Full page reload fixes the issue, from there the styles, since they have been detected, get updated with consecutive hot reloads.

This answer is not convincing, like for what reasons? and how do I avoid it and fix the problem? How do I do a full hot reload when the home page is loaded?

I tried refreshing the page? rerunning the dev server, but still didn't work? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `class` or `id` selectors to apply styles?

Comment: yes, I tried everything so far

Comment: Try `display: inline-block!important`

Comment: I tried this `  border: 5px solid blue !important;` it doesn't work. but if I apply this style from console it works without `important`.

Comment: this is so weird!!

Comment: Then in order to apply the style effect in child components you should use deep selectors https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements

Comment: Yep, if you're using a 3rd party library here, you'll need to make some `::v-deep input` into your style but here...you should not have to do it since it a basic input.

Comment: I tried deep selectors it didn't work either.

Comment: yes, I am using a third party library called `vue-date-pick`, trying to style the input field of it.

Comment: Please provide the full code so we can see. The code you have supplied as an example does not suffer from any scoping or child component deep selector issues.

Comment: that one should have been told at the beginning so far ! ^^ inpesct your DOM and try to find the selector you want to target, should work with the deep selectors. Or give some some [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just updated the question, please see it again. Thank you everyone for helping

Comment: I tried deep selector here `.vdpComponent.vdpWithInput >>> input {` this didn't work as well, but if I remove `scoped` from `style` it works. Don't know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As told in the previous comments, since you're using `SCSS` here and targeting a 3rd party component, you need to write it this way

```css
::v-deep .vdpWithInput input {
  // your fancy style here
}
```

It will help having it scoped in this specific component and not bleeding all over your app.

Useful link for the deep selectors: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors